# How can I make a communication between several docker containers on my local network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-network

I'm currently working on hyperledger blockchain that use several docker containers :

- dev-peer0.org1.example.com-marbles-v5.9
- peer0.org1.example.com
- couchdb
- orderer.example.com
- cli
- ca.example.com

*On the default configuration they are all running on the same machine.*

**What I'm trying to achieve is to divide them on two different computers :**

Computer 1 :

- dev-peer0.org1.example.com-marbles-v5.9
- peer0.org1.example.com
- couchdb

Computer 2 :

- orderer.example.com
- cli
- ca.example.com

**Can I use the host file to make this work without editing any conf file ?**

PC1 :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.31.128.146 orderer.example.com
10.31.128.146 cli
10.31.128.146 ca.example.com
```

PC2:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.31.128.198 dev-peer0.org1.example.com-marbles-v5.9
10.31.128.198 peer0.org1.example.com
10.31.128.198 couchdb
```

I have already tried and I didn't work but I wonder if I should push more into that way ?

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a22daf356b2aab5792ea53e35f66fccef1d7f1aa2b3a2b92dbfbf96a448ea26a_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
    #depends_on:
    #  - orderer.example.com
    #  - peer0.org1.example.com
    #  - couchdb
```

Comment: When running on a single machine, the containers communicate over an "internal" Docker network, private to that machine. When you split the compose file, two networks are made, each private. You need to expose the ports that are to be used for communication. If you supply the compose files you are using, it will be possible to be specific.

Comment: I have added the requested file :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend enabling Swarm Mode for an overlay network. Ideally you can even run the containers inside Swarm Mode, but that's not necessary for just the overlay networking.

One one host, run the following to create a manager:

```
docker swarm init
```

Then run the output `docker swarm join` command on your second host.

---

Option A: for only overlay networking, you need to create a network as attachable to use it outside of swarm mode:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable basic
```

And then in your compose file, adjust the network definition to be external:

```
version: '2'
networks:
  basic:
    external:
      name: basic
```

With that, your containers will be able to communicate directly over the overlay network.

---

Option B: To use Swarm Mode to run the containers, you can skip the network creation and setting the network to external. Just update your version to `version: '3'` inside your compose.yml file, I'd also remove the "container_name" lines. Then run:

```
docker stack deploy -c compose.yml hyperledger
```

to create a stack called hyperledger.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use/add the [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) to each of your compose service definitions if you want to go down the hosts route.