# Hyperledger Fabric multiple hosts setup marbles demo

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have successfully installed a few hyperledger demos, including the marbles one (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles)

A few questions,

1. How can I move some of the marbles demo nodes to another host/s and still get this demo to work?

   I have read the following two posts on the same topic already (where 
   docker-swarm has been used for intra-host communication)

   [How can I set up hyperledger fabric with multiple hosts using Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113916/how-can-i-set-up-)
   hyperledger-fabric-with-multiple-hosts-using-docker &

   [How can I make a communication between several docker containers on my local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825974/how-can-i-make-a-)
   communication-between-several-docker-containers-on-my-local-net

   I still couldn't decipher installing additional nodes and running them 
   on different hosts.

   As running blockchain nodes on multiple hosts seems to be a common task, 
   how is it being done now? I saw references to Cello and an ansible 
   script, though they look not so mature and sure shot solutions.
2. Could I install the fabric nodes manually by pulling the hyperledger/fabric peer images from the docker hub? How do I then install & run the marbles demo on this pulled images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I move some of the marbles demo nodes to another host/s and still get this demo to work?

What do you want to do? I don't understand why you want to move a node. Has it got any sense? If you move some nodes, you are removing them from your Blockchain. If they are part of the Ordering Service or they endorsement is required for the endorsement policy, your demo will not continue running.

The intra-host communication and the communication among multiple docker containers are different things from what you are asking.

> 2. Could I install the fabric nodes manually by pulling the
>      hyperledger/fabric peer images from the docker hub? How do I then
>      install & run the marbles demo on this pulled images?

You can install you nodes manually via the docker-compose. You should define what you want to start up and then execute it. Of course, you should have in your machine the corresponding docker images. Then, you should deploy the marbles Smart Contract in your peers. You have more info about it [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html).

Comment: Thanks Urko for your reply.
 
I would reword my query.  

I want to add more nodes to the blockchain, if i somehow add them,  how do I create the bridge with the main blockchain?

Comment: I don't remember now in which state is this functionality, probably someone could answer this question. However, I think that it hasn't been developed yet.